# how to move accessor methods from model to trait?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, traits, operator-precedence

I have some accessors in my model that I want to move them to a trait but I got an error that dont know how to fix. please help me how to handle that. by the way I am new in laravel!

here is my Merchant model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Merchant;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\Models\Merchant\BankAccount;
use App\Traits\LabelAccessor;

class Merchant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes, LabelAccessor;

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $guarded = ['email_verified_at', 'telephone_verified_at', 'rejcted_at', 
    'profile_verified_at', 'shaparak_verified_at'];

    public function bankAccounts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Merchant\BankAccount');
    }

}
```

and here is my trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;


trait LabelAccessor 
{
protected $appends = [
    'gender_label', 'merchant_type_label', 'residency_type_label', 'vital_status_label', 
    'birth_crtfct_series_letter_label'
];
public function getGenderLabelAttribute()
{
    $label = '';
    switch ($this->gender) {
        case '0':
            $label = 'زن';
            break;
        case '1':
            $label = 'مرد';
            break;
    }
    return $label;
}

public function getMerchantTypeLabelAttribute()
{
    $label = '';
    switch ($this->merchant_type) {
        case '0':
            $label = 'حقیقی';
            break;
        case '1':
            $label = 'حقوقی';
            break;
    }
    return $label;
}

public function getResidencyTypeLabelAttribute()
{
    $label = '';
    switch ($this->residency_type) {
        case '0':
            $label = 'ایرانی';
            break;
        case '1':
            $label = 'غیر ایرانی';
            break;
    }
    return $label;
}

public function getVitalStatusLabelAttribute()
{
    $label = '';
    switch ($this->vital_status) {
        case '0':
            $label = 'در قید حیات';
            break;
        case '1':
            $label = 'فوت شده';
            break;
    }
    return $label;
}

public function getBirthCrtfctSeriesLetterLabelAttribute()
{
    $label = '';
    switch ($this->birth_crtfct_series_letter) {
            case '0':
                $label = 'الف';
                break;
            case '1':
                $label = 'ب';
                break;
            case '2':
                $label = 'ل';
                break;
            case '3':
                $label = 'د';
                break;
            case '4':
                $label = 'ر';
                break;
            case '5':
                $label = '1';
                break;
            case '6':
                $label = '2';
                break;
            case '7':
                $label = '3';
                break;
            case '8':
                $label = '4';
                break;
            case '9':
                $label = '9';
                break;
            case '10':
                $label = '10';
                break;
             case '11':
                $label = '11';
                break;
             case '12':
                $label = 'ش';
                break;
        }
        return $label;
    }
}
```

I got this error :
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model and App\Traits\LabelAccessor define the same property ($appends) in the composition of App\Models\Merchant\Merchant. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible. Class was composed in file C:\xampp\htdocs\milyoona-admin\app\Models\Merchant\Merchant.php on line 11

Comment: you are going to want to define the `appends` on each model, remove it from the trait ... if you really need the trait to do this you can look into how traits can be booted on models

Answer (score 3):

The error is occuring because both your `LabelAccessor` trait and Laravel's `HasAttributes` trait (which is used by default in the `Eloquent` class) include a `$prepends` property. This goes against the nature of [PHP traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.properties):

> If a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property with the same name unless it is compatible (same visibility and initial value), otherwise a fatal error is issued. Before PHP 7.0.0, defining a property in the class with the same visibility and initial value as in the trait, raised an E_STRICT notice.

One workaround suggested by [JarekTkaczyk on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/define-model-attributes-in-trait?page=1#reply=50522) is to use the `getArrayableAppends` method in your trait instead:

```php
protected function getArrayableAppends()
{
    $this->appends = array_unique(array_merge($this->appends, [
      'gender_label', 'merchant_type_label', 'residency_type_label', 'vital_status_label', 
      'birth_crtfct_series_letter_label'
    ]));

    return parent::getArrayableAppends();
}
```